# Basic question : $2\langle v,w\rangle < ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I know my question is a little stupid but if $E$ is a vector space with the Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|$ and with the scalar product associate $\langle.,.\rangle$, $\forall v \in E, \|v\|^2 = \langle v,v\rangle$, how to prove that $2\langle v,w\rangle < \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2$.

We have $v,w \in E$ and $v \neq w$.

I know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but It doesn't resolve my problem... Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: compute $<v-w,v-w>$

Comment: Note that in geometry this is called Al-Kashi or Law of cosines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines : $a^2+b^2-2\langle a\cdot b\rangle=c^2>0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$  ||v||^2 -2(v,w)+ ||w||^2=(v,v)-2(v,w)+(w,w)=(v-w,v-w)>0$$
as $v-w\neq 0$, so $2(v,w) < ||v||^2 + ||w||^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$2\langle v,w\rangle\leqslant2\|u\|.\|v\|\leqslant\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2,$$since$$\bigl(\|u\|-\|v\|\bigr)^2\geqslant0\iff2\|u\|.\|v\|\leqslant\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2.$$